# Numa TextBox, com a propriedade MultiLine true, o carater \n não faz mudar de linha

Tags: c#

Numa TextBox o carater `\n` não faz mudar de linha o texto, exemplo:

```
textBox1.Multiline = true;
textBox1.Text = "IMPRIMEEMCIMA\nIMPRIMEEMBAIXO";
```

No entanto o carater `\t` funciona. Verifiquei também que numa label o mesmo texto imprime a mudança de linha mas não imprime o tab, \t.
Numa MessageBox e numa aplicação Console tudo funciona bem.

Comment: Acho que você tem que fazer `\r\n`

Comment: Funciona, obrigado!

Comment: Beleza, vou responder então

Answer (score 6):

Use o `Environment.NewLine`, que retorna uma string especifica da plataforma em questão:

- "\r\n" (\u000D\u000A) para Windows
- "\n" (\u000A) para Unix

**Exemplo:**

```
textBox1.Text = "IMPRIMEEMCIMA" + Environment.NewLine + "IMPRIMEEMBAIXO";
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Para quebrar a linha no TextBox você deve fazer `\r\n`